Can Virtual Threads improve querying a database in Java?
I wanted to try power of virtual threads in Java in a simple application which consists of many tasks. Each task executes a query agains a database which takes around 10 seconds.
My expectation was that the queries are executed almost at the same time because the significant part of task is basically waiting for the response.
But it doesn't work like that. Unfortunately, I am missing probably something.
In order to execute the tasks, I am using:
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor()

the tasks are executed in a the following way:
StopWatch stopWatch = StopWatch.createStarted();
int numberOfTasks = 10;
List<? extends Future<String>> futures;
try(ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor()) {
     futures = IntStream.range(1, numberOfTasks + 1).mapToObj(i -> new Task(i)).map(executorService::submit).toList();
}
        
for(Future<String> future: futures) {
            future.get();
}
stopWatch.stop();
System.out.println(format("The total time of execution was: {0} ms", stopWatch.getTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)));

The Task.call() method looks like this:
    @Override
    public String call() {
        System.out.println(format("Task: {0} started", taskId));
        StopWatch stopWatch = StopWatch.createStarted();
        Connection connection = null;
        String result = null;
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/sakila?user=sakila&password=sakila");
            System.out.println(format("Task: {0} connection established", taskId));
            var statement = connection.createStatement();
            System.out.println(format("Task: {0} executes SQL statement", taskId));
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT hello_world() AS output");
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                result = resultSet.getString("output");
            }
            statement.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (connection != null && !connection.isClosed()) {
                    connection.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(format("Task: {0} connection closed", taskId));
        }
        stopWatch.stop();
        System.out.println(format("Task: {0} completed in {1} ms", taskId, stopWatch.getTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)));
        return result;
    }


The output is as follows:
Task: 1 started
Task: 5 started
Task: 9 started
Task: 7 started
Task: 3 started
Task: 6 started
Task: 8 started
Task: 2 started
Task: 4 started
Task: 10 started
Task: 1 connection established
Task: 6 connection established
Task: 7 connection established
Task: 9 connection established
Task: 8 connection established
Task: 5 connection established
Task: 7 executes SQL statement
Task: 2 connection established
Task: 1 executes SQL statement
Task: 6 executes SQL statement
Task: 3 connection established
Task: 8 executes SQL statement
Task: 2 executes SQL statement
Task: 5 executes SQL statement
Task: 4 connection established
Task: 4 executes SQL statement
Task: 10 connection established
Task: 10 executes SQL statement
Task: 10 connection closed
Task: 6 connection closed
Task: 10 completed in 10 319 ms
Task: 8 connection closed
Task: 2 connection closed
Task: 2 completed in 10 335 ms
Task: 1 connection closed
Task: 9 executes SQL statement
Task: 3 executes SQL statement
Task: 1 completed in 10 337 ms
Task: 4 connection closed
Task: 4 completed in 10 320 ms
Task: 5 connection closed
Task: 8 completed in 10 336 ms
Task: 6 completed in 10 336 ms
Task: 7 connection closed
Task: 5 completed in 10 338 ms
Task: 7 completed in 10 338 ms
Task: 9 connection closed
Task: 3 connection closed
Task: 9 completed in 20 345 ms
Task: 3 completed in 20 345 ms
The total time of execution was: 20 363 ms

Summary:

In the beginning all Tasks were started.
Secondly, all tasks established a jdbc connection with a database
Only 8 out of 10 tasks started to execute a SELECT statement
The last 2 tasks started to execute the SELECT statement when two task completed their job

Long story short: Since communication with a database is an I/O operation then the virtual threads should execute the SELECTs almost at the same time.
P.S. I have 8 cores CPU.
Thank you a lot for explanations.

The database is also on your computer. So it sounds like your making a query, and the database is taking resources to process the query, so it is not starting the next tasks. You're not really checking the limit of java but your database/os.

Yes, almost certainly your program is IO bound, and more threads won't help it go faster or anything.  I'm not an expert, but I think: virtual threads help when you need many, many threads, not a dozen or so.  If you had a application that had a thousand threads waiting on a slow database, virtual threads could help.  With small numbers of threads, simply blocking the OS thread ("carrier thread") works about the same as using a virtual thread.  Virtual threads aren't "better threads," they're only better in specific applications.

@markspace I am trying to trying to simulate a slow database. The statement: SELECT hello_world() AS output executes a function. The body of the function consists of SLEEP which takes 10 seconds. It means that most of the time, the threads should wait and there is a capacity to do something more.

Well, I think your simulation doesn't work well.  So you'll have to come up with a better test rig to understand if virtual threads are going to work for your app.

I'll add: can you tell us why you are testing virtual threads?  What is wrong with your current system that you think you need virtual threads?  @CodeGrinder

Looks more like the DB is locked to number of cores for active queries than anything else.

Your JDBC connection pool is only allowing 8 simultaneous connections to the database.   This will be configurable, but how to configure it depends on your environment.

Add a mention about StopWatch. And add a mention that you are using MySQL, with the database local on same machine. I see that now in the JDBC URL, but I should not have to dig for that important information.

Also: which version of the MySQL driver are you using? According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77850978/how-to-call-mysql-in-virtual-threads versions before 9.0.0 used synchronized blocks that lead to thread pinning (i.e. a virtual thread blocking a native thread).

I am using: mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.33. Maybe this is the case. I will try to use different database like postgresql or mongoDB to check if I can fetch the data.

By the way, the synchronized pinning goes away in Java 24.


Can VT improve performance?

Yes and no, of course.
VTs share a native thread, so they can't run instructions in parallel beyond the OS capability. But as you aim to have them yield (park) when waiting, it should have helped, IF they were not hooked on mysql internal synchronized blocks.
Mysql driver 9.0.0+ (currently 9.1.0) has ReentrantLock(s) now and it should work as this enabled the virtual thread to go do something else.
(I'll presume you don't have a limit of 8 connections to the DB. It's usually more like 100. You can assert that by temporarily adding a pause to your task after connecting. You can also use a 'sleep(delay)' in mysql, to make statements last longer to prove your tasks can make parallel statements, but you've got a nasty 10 seconds hard statement already. Perhaps there is a difference in the eye of mysqld, but with a 60 seconds pause, you'll have time to show processlist by hand now).
If you are on linux, you can write a small java method to read the "/proc/thread-self/status" on each task to get some outsight from the OS (the 'Pid' row in particular). See http://man.he.net/man5/proc . This would prove on which distinct native OS threads your VTs are running.
For Windoze I used JNA:
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
        <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
        <version>5.15.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
        <artifactId>jna-platform</artifactId>
        <version>5.15.0</version>
    </dependency>

Here is a sample test:
package vttests;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource;
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;

public class TestMysqlWithVirtualThreads {
    record TD(Integer pid, Integer tid) {}
    
    public interface MyKernel32 extends Library  {
        int GetCurrentProcessId();
        int GetCurrentThreadId();
    }
    
    static MyKernel32 K32;
    static {
        try {
            K32 = Native.load("kernel32", MyKernel32.class);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    }
    
    static ThreadLocal<TD> thrDetailsTL = ThreadLocal.withInitial(() -> new TD(pid(), tid()));
    
    static Integer pid() {
        return K32 != null ? K32.GetCurrentProcessId() : null;
    }
    
    static Integer tid() {
        return K32 != null ? K32.GetCurrentThreadId() : null;
    }
    
    static void p(Object msg) {
        TD td = thrDetailsTL.get();
        System.out.println("["+ (Thread.currentThread().isVirtual() ? "V" : "P")+ "/"+ Thread.currentThread().getName()+ "(" + td.pid + "." + td.tid + ")]: "+ msg);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        testVirtualThread(false);
        testVirtualThread(true);
    }
    
    static void testVirtualThread(boolean useVT) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        int cores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        p("\n\n==========================\nprocessors count = " + cores);
        
        int N = 3 * cores;
        int delay = 2000;
        long t0;
        long d;
        
        ExecutorService es = useVT ? Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor() : Executors.newThreadPerTaskExecutor(r -> new Thread(r));
        try (es) {
            t0 = System.nanoTime();
            List<? extends Future<?>> futures = IntStream
                .range(1, N)
                .mapToObj(i -> new T(i, delay))
                .map(es::submit)
                .toList();
            
            //--------
            
            p("waiting for all futures...");
            for(Future<?> future: futures) {
                        future.get();
            }
            d = System.nanoTime()-t0;
            p("waiting futures took "+1e-9*d+" sec");
            
            //--------
            
            p("shutting down es and await termination...");
            t0 = System.nanoTime();
            es.shutdown();
            es.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            d = System.nanoTime()-t0;
            p("shut down took "+1e-9*d+" sec");
            
            //--------
            
            p("closing VirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor...");
            t0 = System.nanoTime();
        }
        
        d = System.nanoTime() - t0;
        p("closing executor took " + 1e-9 * d + " sec");
        
        p("The end.");
    }
    
    static class T implements Runnable {
        int id;
        int delayms;
        String indent;
        
        T(int id, int delayms) {
            this.id = id;
            this.delayms = delayms;
            indent = "\t".repeat(id) +"\\_>";
        }
        
        @Override
        public void run() {
            p(indent + "task " + id + " started, pid=" + pid() + ", tid=" + tid());
            work();
            p(indent + "tast " + id + " ended.");
        }
        
        void work() {
            try {
                MysqlDataSource ds = new MysqlDataSource();
                ds.setServerName("localhost");
                ds.setPort(3306);
                ds.setUser("some-dbUser");
                ds.setPassword("some-dbPass");
                try (Connection c = ds.getConnection();
                    PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement("select sleep(?), connection_id()")
                    ) {
                    ps.setDouble(1, 1e-3*delayms);
                    
                    for(int i=1; i<=3; i++) {
                        p(indent + "call "+i+"starting ... ");
                        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                        p(indent + "call "+i+" finished on connection id "+(rs.next() ? rs.getString(2) : null));
                    }
                }
                
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

What I see here (with 4 cores) is 4 native threads despite creating 12 virtual threads. With driver 8.4, it's slow like yours, with 9.1.0 it behaves as expected.
And now that you restored sanity, the questions remaind: did it help? The answer has more to do with how many threads can you afford.
Would you rather use 20 native threads (more memory) with only 20 connections (less memory) guaranteed to work in parallel, or would you rather have 100 connections (more memory) which are sadly never working on more than the 4 native threads shared by the virtual threads (less memory)?.
Understand, you really only have N cores at work but my point is that one's optimization is often another one's problem... In particular, allowing 20000 virtual threads to share 4 cores will be awesome on the client side, but you'll never get 20000 jdbc connections without severe performance issues.
As always, bring the back pressure at the entry of the system, don't overcommit to work upsteam only to have to deal with the problem downstream.
As a client in most protocols, the number of outgoing connections is likely lower than the number of threads you can tolerate being blocked for a responses. For a server, it's another story. Virtual threads help the servicing side just like async NIO did.
